# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send' при запуске бота aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio

Я получаю ошибку, которая, судя по всему, указывает на отсутствие loop, однако раньше я подобным кодом достаточно часто запускал ботов и у меня всё работало.

Я использовал этот код для запуска бота:

```
async def run_bot():
  dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())
  dp.include_router(user_router)
  reg_all_handlers()
  await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.run(run_bot())
```

И получил ошибку:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
Traceback (most recent call last):
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

Полная ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\project\main.py", line 24, in <module>
    asyncio.run(run_bot())
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\name\PycharmProjects\project\main.py", line 20, in run_bot
    await dp.start_polling(bot)
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 548, in start_polling
    await asyncio.gather(*done)
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 339, in _polling
    user: User = await bot.me()
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 304, in me
    self._me = await self.get_me()
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 1755, in get_me
    return await self(call, request_timeout=request_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\bot.py", line 432, in __call__
    return await self.session(self, method, timeout=request_timeout)
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\session\base.py", line 257, in __call__
    return cast(TelegramType, await middleware(bot, method))
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiogram\client\session\aiohttp.py", line 167, in make_request
    async with session.post(
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1167, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 474, in _request
    handle = tm.start()
  File "C:\Users\name\.virtualenvs\project\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 656, in start
    return self._loop.call_at(when, self.__call__)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 732, in call_at
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
Fatal error on SSL transport
protocol: <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x0000022D16346B90>
transport: <_ProactorSocketTransport fd=-1 read=<_OverlappedFuture cancelled>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 690, in _process_write_backlog
    self._transport.write(chunk)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 365, in write
    self._loop_writing(data=bytes(data))
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 401, in _loop_writing
    self._write_fut = self._loop._proactor.send(self._sock, data)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'
Exception ignored in: <function _SSLProtocolTransport.__del__ at 0x0000022D100851B0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 321, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 316, in close
    self._ssl_protocol._start_shutdown()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 599, in _start_shutdown
    self._write_appdata(b'')
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 604, in _write_appdata
    self._process_write_backlog()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 712, in _process_write_backlog
    self._fatal_error(exc, 'Fatal error on SSL transport')
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\sslproto.py", line 726, in _fatal_error
    self._transport._force_close(exc)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 152, in _force_close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, exc)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 753, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: Добавьте к вопросу ту строку, где возникает ошибка

Comment: @CausonQ , дополнил

Comment: Сильно подозреваю, что ошибка в том коде, который вы не показали

Comment: @andreymal , помимо этого кода ничего, кроме импортов, нету, в файлах из которых идёт импорт никаких функций не запускается, тем более асинхронных, в проекте нигде не открывается новых потоков или процессов

Comment: `user_router` и `reg_all_handlers()` очень жирно намекают, что вы нас обманываете

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена, она заключалась в моей тупости, дело в том что, в main импортировалась функция reg_all_handlers, для которой импортировалась reg_user_handlers, для которой импортировались все хендлеры, для которых импортировались функции генерации кнопок для бота, там был кнопка для добавления бота в канал, в ней была ссылка, в которой через asyncio.run(bot.get_me().username) брался username бота.

Comment: [Я случайно создал д̶в̶е̶ три учётные записи, как их объединить?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)